# Defining __iter__ for two instance variables of different lengths

Tags: python, oop

I have the following class. It has two instance variables represented as arrays. They will not necessarily have the same length:

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self, input):
        self.input = []
        for data in input:
            self.input.append(data)
        self.other_information = []
```

Both `self.input` and `self.other_information` will contain objects from other classes. In my `__str__` method, I will need to iterate over them both. Defining an `__iter__` method to handle an object with an instance variable with a single array is no problem. If the two arrays had the same length, this wouldn't be an issue, but can I do a single `__iter__` method to iterate over two instance variables in my `__str__` method that have different lengths? I've seen the non- OOP posts on here, but what of something like this?

Comment: What do you expect the output to look like?  There are a whole bunch of ways to iterate over two things: zipped, interleaved, one after another, etc.  Which do you want to use?

Comment: Sequentially. One array, then the other. Really unsure of my options in an oop context. In a functional context, I can do anything. This seems different.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain, then; it's not clear why the lengths are relevant. Or just write the functional version, Python is multi-paradigm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use itertools.chain() to iterate on your two arrays sequentially

```
import itertools


class A(object):
    def __init__(self, input):
        self.input = []
        for data in input:
            self.input.append(data)
        self.other_information = list(range(5))

    def __iter__(self):
        return itertools.chain(self.input, self.other_information)


a = A(['a', 'b', 'c'])

for i in a:
    print(i)

# a
# b
# c
# 0
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
```

You can also use "yield from". The result will be the same.

```
def __iter__(self):
    yield from self.input
    yield from self.other_information
```